# AS3: How to Control Sound Channel of Another Scene from Inside a MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

can you help me? Im a beginer im programming and I'm just barely know as3. I have a problem controlling my bg sound using as3 script from inside a movieclip.

I have an as3 flash project with multiple scene (let's say it sceneA and sceneB), and i placed my sound channel script at SceneA frame 1. I've been able to stop and play my music from sceneA without any trouble. Now at sceneB i have a movieclip and inside it, there's button stop and play. The problem is, I can't use the same method from sceneA to control my music from inside the movieclip of sceneB. How can i do it? Please i need your help.

Here's my sound channel script from sceneA frame 1:

```
var bgm:bgSound = new bgSound();
var sChnl:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var myVolume:SoundTransform = newSoundTransform();
sChnl = bgm.play(0,999,myVolume);
```

Here's my sceneA button stop script, this button is called btnStop:

```
function musicStop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
SoundMixer.stopAll();
bntStop.visible=false;
btnPlay.visible=true;
}
```

Here's the play button called btnPlay:

```
function musicPlay(event:MouseEvent):void
{
sChnl = bgm.Play(0,999,myVolume);
bntStop.visible=true;
btnPlay.visible=false;
}
```

I tried the button play script from sceneA in my SceneB button play and it give me an error:

```
Symbol 'Symbol 1', Layer 'btn control', frame 1, Line 22     1120: Access of undefined property bgm.
```

That's one of the error massage, the other two is the same just that the bgm is myVolume and sChnl.

I have tried this function before

```
MovieClip(root).sChnl = bgm.Play(0,999,myMusic);
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Don't program on timelines, program in classes. With class static fields/methods or singleton pattern you may have this sound control thing accessible from anywhere without actually thinking of any weird ways to access it.

Comment: Uh, you mean separate the as3 script from the fla file like external as3 script?

Comment: Yes, AS3 classes. A good way to program in AS3.